# Potential issue with subscription on event with Angular

Tags: angular, observable

Can subscribing to a service during an event (e.g with clicking a button) bring issue when done without a [Subscription](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subscription) object ? For instance, here is a small snippet I stumbled upon:

```
usernames: string[];

...

public getFullName(userID: string)  {
    this.restApi.getFullName(userID).subscribe(response => {
        this.usernames.push(response);
    });
}
```

I was wondering if a subscription was "added" for each call to the service ? (the first call adds a subscription, which pushes one item, then a second adds another subscription to this Observable and pushes an item twice, and so on and so on)

It is a better practice to subscribe to every services in an OnInit() method, so that you subscribe only once without memory / performance issues ? Or use a Subscription object to make sure that your subscription is "overrid" when called a second time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The less subscriptions you have, the better chances that your app will work without any memory issue.

The code above is dangerous enough because you subscribe for every event and you never unsubscribe.

In other words, If you need to create a subscription on every click you can support it but If you could just create one subscription on initialized it would more efficient.

I would suggest you to read this article: [when-to-unsubscribe](https://netbasal.com/when-to-unsubscribe-in-angular-d61c6b21bad3)
and this one: [how-to-unsubscribe](https://blog.bitsrc.io/6-ways-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-in-angular-ab912819a78f)

**#Edit**

I really like the code of the other answer here by *@MoxxiManagarm*, just leaving my two words because I really believe that this articles are helpful If someone ends up reading this question.

Comment: Those articles were helpful, and it is a more generic answer with that ! Thank you very much !

Comment: If this was helpful, but @Moxxis answer was the one that you use, I suggest you to vote up both and mark Moxxi's as accepted. You are welcome.

Comment: It solves the usecase, however the usecase was an example. I prefer the generic answer, as it applies to every use case. You're the accepted one. Have a nice day !

Answer (score 1):

Your doubts are true. I recommend the `scan` operator for your usecase.

```
lastUserIdRequested: Subject<string> = new Subject();
usernames: string[];

ngOnInit() {
  this.lastUserIdRequested.pipe(
    concatMap(userId => this.restApi.getFullName(userId)),
    scan((acc, fullname) => [...acc, fullname], []),
  ).subscribe(fullnames => this.usernames = fullnames);
}

public getFullName(userId: string) {
  // this could be called directly from template without the getFullName method
  this.lastUserIdRequested.next(userId);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, for this particular usecase, `scan` seems awesome. But it may be an issue for any kind of instructions stored in a `subscribe` and the consequences can be way more dangerous. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Everytime `getFullName` a new subscription is added, so yes; Performances will suffer for this. You could use a `scanner` as MoxxiManagarm said or you can simplify the logic using `takeWhile`:

```
public getFullName(userID: string)  {
    let isAlive = true;
    this.restApi.getFullName(userID).pipe(
    takeWhile(() => isAlive)
    ).subscribe(response => {
        isAlive = false;
        this.usernames.push(response);
    });
}
```

The `takeWhile` operator closes the subscripion and removes it when a certain condition is reached.

Comment: Why not to use `take(1)`?

Comment: I totally forgot about `take`. He could also use `first()`. Both of these operators -should- unsubscribe automatically.

Comment: Keep in mind that ["take(1) will not fire (and complete the observable stream) in case the original observable never emits."](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/the-best-way-to-unsubscribe-rxjs-observable-in-the-angular-applications-d8f9aa42f6a0).